# Accessing another user's MyDocuments folder.

Tags: c#, .net, windows, filesystems

Is there any build-in way in the BCL of retrieving **another user's** MyDocuments directory path? 
Another library would also be great of course.

I'd like not to go through the registry, if that is somehow possible.

background is: I have an application running as a Windows service, which shall produce output in the MyDocuments folder of the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have in the mean time solved this problem by writing to `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments` which became available in .NET 4.0